# Focus is not going inside EventHandler

Tags: sharepoint

I had created a simple web part with one label, and one button. I wnat that when i click the button the label content will change.
But when i debugg i found that the focus is not going inside the Button Click Event function.
When i click the button the debugger will again start with page load.
Is there any Autofocus for Button.
Please help me to resolve my problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're confused about what happens on the client (within the browser) and what happens on the server (in your ASP.NET code).

Most events on server-side controls, like the ASP.NET button, are handled server-side, through a mechanism called postback. The generated code on the browser causes a form submit to the Web server, where the page and its controls are re-created. The form data is parsed and the button control generates (in your case) a Click event for your server-side code. This code regenerates a new HTML page which will replace the old one.

Fortunately for you in this case, the ASP.NET button has a property "OnClientClick" where you can insert JavaScript code to do whatever you want (like change the label text) directly in the browser.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) for the docs on the property and an example of using both Click and OnClientClick.

Note that this is not related to SharePoint, this is a pure ASP.NET issue.